# Sandboxie not Working on Windows 10

Tags: firefox, windows-10-preview, sandbox, sandboxie

I am having an issue with Sandboxie not working on the latest build of Windows 10. Every time I try to start a program in a sandbox, I get the following error.

[image: "Cannot start sandboxed service" Error]

I understand that Sandboxie requires extensive work in order to function when a new version of Windows is made, but I have seen Sandboxie work on Windows 10 with Firefox, and that is what I am trying to sandbox. How can I resolve this? I have uninstalled and reinstalled Sandboxie multiple times with no luck.

Comment: Your using the current version of Sandboxie and the current build of Windows 10?  This the same installation you were having other problems on?  Looks like a conflict with Sandboxie and Windows 10.  You should report the issue to the Sandboxie developers.  I have the same issue, my virtual machine is pristine, I also have this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I have been playing with this problem for hours, and minutes after posting, I found that installing the beta version of Sandboxie resolves the issue. http://forums.sandboxie.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=21354

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sandboxie 4.20 is not compatible with Windows 10.

You will have to wait until it is.  The next release(5.01), currently in beta testing, will have support Windows 10.  There are a known issues with Windows 10, some of them have been fixed, some of them are still pending.

[Source](http://forums.sandboxie.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=21354)

It is worth pointing out the following about the current 5.01 release of SBIE.

> SBIE Beta v5 does not support Windows Metro Apps or the Edge browser
>   at this time. You will need to change your default web browser in Win
>   10 from Edge to something else.
>
> Fixes in 5.01.12
>
> 1) More fine tuning of service start to fix rare race condition that
>   leads to SBIE2303 Could not hook PowerSettingRegisterNotification (1).
>   SBIE 2204 Cannot start sandboxed service RpcSs (-1) cycling every 30
>   seconds.

Answer (score 3):

SBIE Beta v5 does not support Windows Metro Apps or the Edge browser at   this time. You will need to change your default web browser in Win 10   from Edge to something else.

Combined 32/64 installer:

www.sandboxie.com/SandboxieInstall-501-11.exe

Separate:
http://www.sandboxie.com/SandboxieInstall32-501-11.exe
http://www.sandboxie.com/SandboxieInstall64-501-11.exe

Fixes in 5.01.11
1) Service start timing changes to fix rare race condition that leads to   SBIE2303 Could not hook PowerSettingRegisterNotification (1). SBIE 2204   Cannot start sandboxed service RpcSs (-1) cycling every 30 seconds.   This bug is machine dependent.

Comment: I am aware that Sandboxie does blue support Windows Metro Apps. The issue that I was having was with Sandboxie not working was for traditional computer programs on Windows 10.

Comment: This just repeats what I indicated over a month ago.  All It does is points to the current beta version of 5.01.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Beta version (5.01.3) of Sandboxie should work on Windows 10. Be mindful that this is a Beta version and may have bugs and/or errors.

Combined 32/64 installer

http://www.sandboxie.com/SandboxieInstall-501-3.exe